# Why while loop is not looping through the collection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables.

InspectionUTG and InspectionHistoryUTGTML.

```
select distinct InspectionUTGID
from InspectionHistoryUTG
```

It returns

```
5196
5197
5198
5199
5200
```

-- step 2: get one id eg : 5260 from above result

```
select top 1 UserTmin, RLTMin
from InspectionHistoryUTGTML
where InspectionUTGID = 5260 and RLTMin is not null
order by RLTMin
```

-- step 3: Get UserTmin returned from above query i.e. 33.17 and use it below against TMin in below query

```
update InspectionHistoryUTG set
  TMin = 33.17
where InspectionUTGID = 5260
```

Now what I have done is

```
create table #TableInspectionsUTGs
(
    InspectionUTGID int
)

Insert into #TableInspectionsUTGs
  select distinct InspectionUTGID from InspectionHistoryUTG

Select #TableInspectionsUTGs.InspectionUTGID from #TableInspectionsUTGs

While ((Select Count(#TableInspectionsUTGs.InspectionUTGID) from #TableInspectionsUTGs) > 0)
Begin
  select top 1 UserTmin ,RLTMin
  from InspectionHistoryUTGTML 
  where InspectionUTGID = #TableInspectionsUTGs.InspectionUTGID and RLTMin is not null order by RLTMin 
End
```

But it's not working. I just want to use each `InspectionUTGID` returned in first query against the `InspectionUTGID` 
in where clause of second query and then using the `UserTmin` returned in 2nd query against the `TMin` in 3 query.

Comment: 1) You don't appear to use table `InspectionUTG` - all your queries use `InspectionHistoryUTG`. 2) Some sample data showing the initial data and the expected result, even if just for a single ID would make this question a whole lot clearer.

Comment: And then you reference table `InspectionHistoryUTGTML` - so the question is currently inconsistent with table naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, i.e. update `Tmin` in `InspectionHistoryUTG` based on the most recent value of `UserTmin` in `InspectionHistoryUTGTML` then you're going about in a procedural way as if you were writing regular code. However when writing SQL one needs to embrace set based coding because that is how SQL Server works and performs.

So what you are trying to accomplish can probably be achieved with a single SQL update statement as follows:

```
declare @InspectionHistoryUTG table (InspectionUTGID int, TMin int);
declare @InspectionHistoryUTGTML table (InspectionUTGID int, UserTmin int, RLTMin int);

insert into @InspectionHistoryUTG (InspectionUTGID)
  select 1
  union all select 2
  union all select 3;

insert into @InspectionHistoryUTGTML (InspectionUTGID, RLTMin, UserTmin)
  select 1, 1, 1
  union all select 1, 2, 2
  union all select 1, 3, 3
  union all select 2, 1, 3
  union all select 2, 2, 2
  union all select 2, 3, 1
  union all select 3, 1, 2
  union all select 3, 2, 3
  union all select 3, 3, 1;

--select * from @InspectionHistoryUTG;
--select * from @InspectionHistoryUTGTML;

update IH set
  TMin = (
      select top 1 IHT.UserTmin
      from @InspectionHistoryUTGTML IHT
      where IHT.InspectionUTGID = IH.InspectionUTGID and IHT.RLTMin is not null
      order by IHT.RLTMin
    )
from @InspectionHistoryUTG IH
-- Following where clause won't update if a single null TML record exists as per OPs comment
where not exists (
  select 1
  from @InspectionHistoryUTGTML IHT
  where IHT.InspectionUTGID = IH.InspectionUTGID and IHT.RLTMin is null
)

select * from @InspectionHistoryUTG;
--select * from @InspectionHistoryUTGTML;
```

We just use a regular update statement on `InspectionHistoryUTG` with a sub-query on `InspectionHistoryUTGTML` to obtain the required value for `TMin` for the current value of `InspectionUTGID`.

So instead of updating `InspectionHistoryUTG` one row at a time using multiple selects and updates, we do the whole lot in one hit.

Note: This is also how you should present your questions in future because it means that people willing to assist can just copy and paste the SQL into their query analyser and start working on it with valid sample data.

Comment: but there's a problem, update should not run for a InspectionUTGID if there's even a single NULL in the column UserTmin in the collection of InspectionHistoryUTG returned... but it is working

Comment: Based on your comment you would add the following line to the update `where not exists (select 1
      from @InspectionHistoryUTGTML IHT
      where IHT.InspectionUTGID = IH.InspectionUTGID and IHT.RLTMin is null)`